# override app lib than Mule/lib/boot jars

Tags: java, mule, log4j2

Im using Mule-3.9.0 standalone version and my app uses log4j2 version 2.3. But the Mule comes with log4j version 2.8.2. I cannot upgrade my app's log4j2 version due to some dependency issue, so I tried to over this by using

```
   loader.override=com.apache.logging.log4j
```

in mule-deploy.properties so that it picks my app's log4j but that also didnt work.

Another try I did with moving all the log files to app/classes/ folder but that prints entire log with DEBUG, where as I've not mentioned debug level anywhere.

I mainly want to override my app lib jars during class loading Can some please help me? I've got blocked with this issues

Answer (score 0):

You are using package *com*.apache.logging.log4j but the correct package for Apache log4j2 is ***org*.apache.logging.log4j**

Remember, Apache is an organization, not a company.

Hope that helps.